# change the list object hibernate return

Tags: java, hibernate

when i create in my server side query in hibernate

```
(em.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select..."))
```

form some object that include java list 
hibernate return `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList`

now when i try to send this object my java client side he don't know this

```
org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList
```

object when i try to deserialize (and i don't want to add this hibernate.jar to the client side).

there is a way to make hibernate to return ordinary java list?
for now i replace this list every  query to  ordinary java list or java Arraylist
and then i send this object to client side.
(Json is not an option).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally hibernate objects are not serializable. If you want to send them to the client, you have to copy their data into data holder objects (or you can use a special software package for your client). This is not only the case for the list implementation, but also for single pojos, and lazy loading normally also won't work on the client side.

You're already doing it the right way, you copy the elements of the list into a new list for the client. That needs only a very small amount of time compared with the time necessary for reading the data from the database.

(I don't know which software you're using on the client side. If it is GWT, [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate) you can find a good documentation for the hibernate integration. But probably you're not using GWT because GWT has much bigger obstacles for the hibernate integration than only the PersistentList.)